# Apache .htaccess rewrite url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite the url `http://127.0.0.1/subscribe/paypal/203/` so that I can get values with php like so

```
$mode = $_GET['mode'];
$package_id=$_GET['id'];

var_dump($mode);//outputs visa
var_dump($package_id);//outputs 203
```

and also when the user makes a mistake and types `http://127.0.0.1/subscribe/paypal/` it takes them to `http://127.0.0.1/subscribe.php`

My .htaccess file's contents are as shown below.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^subscribe/.*/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  subscribe.php?mode=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your `/.htaccess` file

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase / 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subscribe/paypal/?$
 RewriteRule ^subscribe/(.*)/?$ /subscribe.php?mode=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
 RewriteRule ^subscribe/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  /subscribe.php?mode=$1&id=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: This almost does it, however when the user types "http://127.0.0.1/subscribe/paypal/" the "$_GET['mode']" is not set to anytthing. I want to get the mode so that I can redirect

Comment: Thanks. Works as expected